# Left and Right Columns

Tags: layout, css

I am relatively new using magento, and I'm having issues removing/editing the left and right columns.  I have the columns enabled, and trying to remove the pictures/links that are defaulted in those sections.  My widgets that are enabled for my columns are not overwriting that script.

Yesterday I was making headway with editing this, with the app>design>default>default>design>frontend>template files.  Now those files disappeared but were not deleted. I copied the files from another skin and began working on those, but there seems to be some missing as there are not as many as there were.

Comment: Magento1: Sounds confusing. However you can change what you want in etc/...layout/default/yourtheme/

Or you can overwrite it in custom layout via the backend, to be removed. Every "block" has a name that is used to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you need to remove form the all pages?**

```
Left and right columns block coming form the .xml files you can remove form their

Or you can set layout like 2-column-left or right.
```

**Create a local.xml in you theme**

```
<reference name="left">
    <remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />
    <remove name="catalog.product.related" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento using layout for design purpose and we have different part In layout

Just like :content, left , right ,head, header, footer

we can add and remove any content from them just writing below code

For Example

```
<reference name="left">
   <remove name="name of that block" />
</reference>
```

Refrence could anthing from above Hope this will help you to understand the magento layout.